# how to create html table from python dictionary with repeated column name inside list

Tags: python, html

The Following Data is I am getting from Database i want to make table in html with this data

```
[{'id': 1}, {'e': 2}, {'i': 3}, {'id': 12}, {'e': 12}, {'i': 23},
 {'id': 13}, {'e': 3}, {'i': None}, {'id': 14}, {'e': 23},
 {'i': None}, {'id': 123}, {'e': 123}, {'i': 123}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
data = [{'id': 1}, {'e': 2}, {'i': 3}, {'id': 12}, {'e': 12}, {'i': 23},
 {'id': 13}, {'e': 3}, {'i': None}, {'id': 14}, {'e': 23},
 {'i': None}, {'id': 123}, {'e': 123}, {'i': 123}]


def chunker(seq, size):
    # from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/434328/11384184
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))


print(f"|id|e|i|")
for id_obj, e_obj, i_obj in chunker(data, 3):
    print(f"|{id_obj['id']}|{e_obj['e']}|{i_obj['i']}|")

# |id|e|i|
# |1|2|3|
# |12|12|23|
# |13|3|None|
# |14|23|None|
# |123|123|123|
```

I just `print`ed the result, but it should be simple to generate the corresponding HTML from there.